# Uniform convergence​ and integral

Tags: analysis

[image]

For the first part, I can only show that the function is uniform convergent for x < 1. For the second part I gave spotted that the bit inside the bracket is 1/fn(x) but how does this relate to the integral?

Comment: Why did you have trouble bounding $\sup \lvert{\frac{n}{n+t} - 1\rvert}$ for $t > 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\sup_{t\in[0,x]}\vert f_n(t)-1\vert=1-\frac{n}{n+x}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
which prove the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to the constant function $1$. Hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln(1+x/n) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+\frac tn}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^xf_n(t)dt=\int_0^xdt=x$$
and we deduce the result using the continuity of the exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Why could you not show for $t>1$?

Integrate $f_n(t)$ and use Dominated convergence theorem (the f=1 function dominates it) to say that the limit over n can be taken both inside and outside the integral, without changing the value. Take exponential on both sides. This should be what the question asks for.